# Need a dict with my own custom Pair type?

Tags: c#, dictionary

`KeyValuePair` doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so I've implemented my own `Pair` type, but I want to use it in a dictionary.

What's the easiest way to do that?

---

So here's the deal. In my code I need a dictionary with key/value pairs. This doesn't really need to be observable.

I have an edit window though, that displays this dict in a datagrid. That needs to be observable so that the datagrid can work its magic.

So what I've done is make make the edit window accept any enumerable of pairs:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Pair<string,object>> Variables { get; private set; }

    public VariablesWindow(IEnumerable<Pair<string, object>> vars)
    {
        Variables = new ObservableCollection<Pair<string, object>>(vars.DeepCopy());
```

So that it can do its thing. And then in the main code I use a dict like normal, but when I open the edit window I have to convert the dict into something the edit window can use:

```
var window = new VariablesWindow(Dict2Enum(_dict));
```

So I've added these 2 helper methods:

```
    private static IEnumerable<Pair<TKey, TValue>> Dict2Enum<TKey, TValue>(Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        return dict.Select(i => new Pair<TKey, TValue>(i.Key, i.Value));
    }

    private static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Enum2Dict<TKey, TValue>(IEnumerable<Pair<TKey, TValue>> collection)
    {
        return collection.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
    }
```

Seems a bit expensive though. I'm looping over the collection twice now. Once to convert the dictionary to an enumerable, then again to deep copy it so that the variables don't get changed until the user hits save, and then I convert that enumerable into an observable collection.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `KeyValuePair`? Why not implement it for TKey or TValue in `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>`?

Comment: When would you need this?  KeyValuePair has only 2 properties, and they're both read-only.

Comment: @The Smartest: TKey is a string, TValue is an object. Don't think I can implement it for native types like that, unless I wrap it like Jon suggests. @Ken: Well I guess I don't want them to be read-only either.

Comment: Could `ILookup` help you in some way?

Comment: @Jani: ILookup is used for 1-key-to-many-value dicts, isn't it? Not what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to notify of a *value* changing? If so, I'd consider writing a `Wrapper<T>` class which supported `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and then using (say) `Dictionary<string, Wrapper<int>>` (for a "string/int" dictionary which supports notification of changes).

Note that this will mean that anyone who keeps a reference to the wrapper will see the changes made to the value - it's something you'd have to be quite careful about.

EDIT: To expand on my comments somewhat...

If you want to be able to edit the key as well, I suspect you'll that for a mutable TKey/TValue pair you'll want a `Dictionary<TKey, MutablePair<TKey, TValue>>`. You'll need to support `INotifyPropertyChanging` as well as `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and it would get somewhere hairy... you may need to *remove* it by key on `INotifyPropertyChanging`, and then re-add it on `INotifyPropertyChanged`. No doubt things would get messy if the change was abandoned half way through. You'd also need to work out what you'd want to happen if one key overwrote another... and then the original object was changed:

```
// Rough code - imagine we'd got a wrapper around Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
// to create the pairs automatically.
oddDictionary["key1"] = "value1";
oddDictionary["key2"] = "value2";

var pair1 = oddDictictionary.GetMutablePair("key1");
var pair2 = oddDictictionary.GetMutablePair("key2");
pair1.Key = "key2"; // Overwrite pair2, presumably...
// Does the "changing" remove pair1? Or check for consistency? As it's
// not part of the dictionary before the operation, does this not affect
// the dictionary at all?
pair2.Key = "key3";
```

Basically there's a lot of semantics you need to think through *really* carefully before going much further.

I suggest you write *lots* of unit tests for the behaviour you want to implement, and then see what you can do.

Comment: Both. I'd like to keys to be editable too. Trying to allow users to edit the dict however they please.

Comment: @Ralph: It doesn't make sense to edit the key *within* the dictionary - that means removing the previous entry from the dictionary and adding a new one.

Comment: @Jon: I think it makes perfect sense. You might have an object with a string property, and you might need a dictionary keyed by that property. You’d want the dictionary to auto-update when that property changes.

Comment: @Timwi: Then you're going to have to make sure that whenever you create such a dictionary, it subscribes to the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event and performs the appropriate change. You'd actually need it to subscribe to `INotifyPropertyChanging` so it could see the change *before* the key changed... otherwise it wouldn't know which entry to remove.

Comment: @Jon: I don't care how it gets done (edit or delete and re-add), I just need that functionality. It's like renaming a variable in your code.

Comment: @Ralph: No, it's *not* like renaming a variable in your code, because that's not happening at execution time, with all kinds of weirdness going on... and if there's a duplicate variable name, the compiler gets to complain. Would you throw an exception instead? That would be the rough equivalent. See my edit for some other oddness. You need to think very carefully about this.

Comment: @Jon: Good call on the duplicate key issue. Overlooked that..haha. I'll just display an error so the user can't enter dupes. Or I could quietly delete one. Didn't think this editing-a-dict thing would be so complicated. Maybe I'll just leave it the way I have it then.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample which can be used as a reference:

http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/

Comment: "Also, a dictionary exposes its Values and Keys collections through separate properties of the same name.  These collections are of types Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ValueCollection and Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection, respectively.  These CLR-defined collections are not observable.  As such, you cannot bind to the Values collection or to the Keys collection directly and expect to receive dynamic collection change notifications.  You must instead bind directly to the observable dictionary." -- well, that kind of defeats the purpose.

Comment: Agree, as it is not designed for this purpose. Have you tried this code?

Comment: There's no sense trying it. I *need* to bind on the key and value, not the entire dict.